# pip install pyodbc is not working and Facing Error : Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement of pyodbc

Tags: python, installation, pip, pyodbc

Error :

```
 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement of pyodbc (from versions: ).
 No matching distribution found for Pyodbc.
```

Traceback :

```
C:\Users\Administrator> pip install pyodbc
collecting pyodbc

Retrying (Retry(total=s, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolErr]
r (‘Connection aborted. *, ConnectionResetError (10034, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host’,
ne, 10054, None)’: /simple/pyodbe/

Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolErr]
r (‘Connection aborted. *, ConnectionResetError (10034, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host’,
ne, 10054, None))': /simple/pyodbe/

Retrying’ (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolErr]
r (‘Connection aborted. *, ConnectionResetError (10034, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host’,
ne, 10054, None))': /simple/pyodbe/

Retrying (Retry(total=l, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolErr]
r (‘Connection aborted. , ConnectionResetError (10034, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host’,
ne, 10054, None))': /simple/pyodbe/

Retrying’ (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolErr]
r (‘Connection aborted. *, ConnectionResetError (10034, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host’,
ne. 10054, None)": /simple/pyodbe/.
```

Now one solution is that I need to download manually through link but I know that.

Comment: You are mistaken. The error is not `Could not find a version`, but all the connection errors you are getting above it. This is a problem in your network/pip configuration and has nothing to do with `pyodbc`, you will see the same for any other package you try to `pip install` from PyPi

Comment: Please include infrmation about your network, i.e. is it your home network or a company or instiution; about your python setup, i.e. how did you install it and which version are you running. Please also make sure to always add complete error messages and traceback **as text**. don't use screenshots, unless the error is actually related to something visual

Comment: @FlyingTeller Okay. I will do correctin. yes it's company's network. 3.7.0 python version. What should I do to resolve this error ?

Comment: Ask your IT department about Proxy settings you need to set. This is an issue of pip not being able to connect to Pypi